# Using cell value to specify the paste location in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with two rows : the first row contains the locations where the value of the second row should be pasted.

For example :

```
row 1 : sheet8!D2  sheet6!D2   sheet2!C5
row 2 : apple      lemon       pEER
```

So apple should be pasted in sheet 8 cell D8. Lemon should be pasted in sheet6 cell D2. The problem is that the value apple is pasted everywhere (in `sheet8!D2`, `sheet6!D2` and `sheet2!C5`). How can I correct this?

```
Sub Sample()
Dim rng As Range
Dim Sh As String, Cl As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim Row1 As String

ncol = Range("A1:F1").Columns.Count

For i = 1 To ncol


Row1 = Range("A1:F1").Cells(1, i).Value

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With ws
    Sh = Split(Row1, "!")(0)
    Cl = Split(Row1, "!")(1)

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sh).Range(Cl)

    rng.Value = .Range("A2").Value

End With

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.  First up its good practice to put Option Explicit at the top of each module, this will ensure variables are defined (`ncol` is not defined).

The following code will fix the problem although it could be tweaked in various ways.  The main problem is you don't quite set the referencing ranges correctly, you move through the columns with your loop but always refer back to cell A2.  Assuming your input data is on rows 1 and 2 and run from the sheet with that data this will work.

```
Sub SampleFixed()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Sh As String, Cl As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, ncol As Integer
    Dim Row1 As String

    ncol = Range("A1:F1").Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To ncol
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        With ws
            Row1 = .Cells(1, i).Value

            If Len(Row1) > 0 Then
                Sh = Split(Row1, "!")(0)
                Cl = Split(Row1, "!")(1)
                Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sh).Range(Cl)

                'Here you were always refering to cell A2 not moving through the values which was the main problem.
                rng.Value = .Cells(2, i).Value     
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Agree with option explicit